# Dummy ActiveRecord model in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a module that adds some functionality to ActiveRecord. To test this model, I'd like to create a dummy model in RSpec, so that I'm independent on my production models:

```
describe MyModule do
  before do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :articles, force: true do |t|
      t.string(:name)
    end
  end

  after do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.drop_table(:articles, if_exists: true)
  end

  class Article < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :author
  end

  class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :articles
  end

  it "does some stuff" do
    ...
  end
end
```

The problem is, Rubocop complains with `RSpec/LeakyConstantDeclaration` and suggests to extract the fixed classes into `let`:

```
  let(:article_class) do
    Class.new(ApplicationRecord) do
      has_many :comments
    end
  end
  let(:author_class) do
    Class.new(ApplicationRecord) do
      has_many :articles
    end
  end

  before do
    stub_const("Article", article_class)
    stub_const("Author", author_class)
  end
```

This works perfectly when I run a single test. But when I run multiple tests they fail because articles and / or authors are missing. It seems like past tests influence other tests.

It seems like ActiveRecord doesn't play well with such definitions of models. So I'd like to know if there is a better way to define dummy models in RSpec?

Comment: Does article_class be accessed before stub_const("Article", article_class)?

Comment: Does it really have to be a model or would it be possible to use a class double? It would really help to see a test and the object under test.

Comment: sorry, totally missed these comments: It's for a library that provides eager loading of ActiveRecord, so real objects in the DB are needed and a class double would not be sufficient

Comment: I know it's an old one, since I am working on it, might as well give my 2 cents. How did you refer to the `Article` and `Author` in the tests? Once you instantiate the anonymous class (also stubbing the class name) and assign them to a `let`  you can start referring through the defined `let`, eg. `author_class.new` or `author_class.create` instead of `Article.create`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the gem `anonymous_active_record` to solve this problem exactly.
https://github.com/pboling/anonymous_active_record

If you have some code you want to test against a "real" ActiveRecord model:

```
module HasBalloon
  def has_balloon?
    name == 'Spot' # only Spot has a balloon
  end
end
```

You can install the gem, then require it in your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'anonymous_active_record'
```

And then write a test:

```
let(:ar_with_balloon) do
  AnonymousActiveRecord.generate(columns: ['name']) do
    include HasBalloon
    def flowery_name
      "#{b_f}#{name}#{b_f}"
    end
    def b_f
      has_balloon? ? '' : ''
    end
  end
end
it 'can test the module' do
  expect(ar_with_balloon.new(name: 'Spot').flowery_name).to eq('Spot')
  expect(ar_with_balloon.new(name: 'Not Spot').flowery_name).to eq('Not Spot')
end
```

That's all!  It depends on sqlite under the hood for the magical tables.

Answer (score -1):

You could extract a [shared context](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context)

```rb
RSpec.shared_context 'with test tables  and models' do 
  before do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :articles, force: true do |t|
      t.string(:name)
    end

    stub_const("Article", article_class)
    stub_const("Author", author_class)
  end

  after do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.drop_table(:articles, if_exists: true)
  end

  let(:article_class) do
    Class.new(ApplicationRecord) do
      has_many :comments
    end
  end

  let(:author_class) do
    Class.new(ApplicationRecord) do
      has_many :articles
    end
  end
```

and include it in each of the test that needs it.

```rb
describe MyModule do
  include_context 'with test tables  and models' 

  # your examples here
end
```

Comment: that doesn't fix the problem that ActiveRecord behaves weird when dealing with anonymous classes